# Protocol relative links do not work on the Android app

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app, hyperlinks

Protocol relative links (e.g. `//google.com`) are not clickable in the Android app (version 1.0.57, Nexus 7 (2012)). However, images with protocol relative links are working fine on 1.0.56.

Test case (with protocol relative links):

- [Link to this question](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/248569/protocol-relative-links-do-not-work-on-the-android-app/)
- Image:

  [image]

[Kudos to minitech for finding this bug.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285841/should-potentially-useful-self-deleted-questions-be-undeleted?noredirect=1#comment155294_285841)

Comment: Actually, do *any* links work in the Android app?

Comment: Using the Android app (1.0.56) on my phone, the test case works for me without any issues.

Comment: Glad to know that someone else is the world is having about as exciting of a Valentine's Day as I am.

Comment: I thought the images didn't load as well?

Comment: Working fine in the iOS app.

Comment: @rene Images with protocol relative links are working fine on 1.0.56.

Comment: I previously upvoted this post and hadn't upvoted Kevin's comment, meaning that I could reproduce this bug. However, now I couldn't repro it on Nexus 5, Android 6.0.1, SE app 1.0.82 (beta)...

Comment: @AndrewT. so why did you delete your answer? It's legit, you can mark it as CW if you don't feel you deserve rep. (And no repro for me too, so likely it has been fixed indeed)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I deleted my answer after reading Kevin's comment, since I couldn't conclude if it's really fixed, or just a coincidence with specific device/Android version. I might even suspect Android `WebView` as another factor now. So I guess it's better to leave it to Kasra & team (sorry). **Edit:** I undeleted my answer for now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of v1.0.82* (beta)<sup>or somewhere before that</sup>, it has been fixed: protocol relative links are now clickable, and working as intended.

<sup>*tested on Nexus 5 on Android 6.0.1 Marshmallow</sup>